# pandas how to get data form google sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

The following script generates this error: `err:HTTPError: HTTP Error 432: unknown`.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas

googleSheetId = '1iJnkfdDLC_4SHlaWNEbBS0kiJkmE4oEV'
worksheetName = 'Hourly%20Market%20Data'
URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{0}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={1}'.format(
              googleSheetId, worksheetName)

df = pandas.read_csv(URL)
df.head(10)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#using-gspread-with-pandas maybe?

Comment: the code should get data from big shpreadsheet